# JWT to prevent others from using video in their iframes

Tags: jwt, json, end-to-end-encryption

I just recently discovered JWT to secure my live stream and have done successful token on server and player but I think it still can be stolen.

How I can use it to only have the domains I choose to be able to access the stream?

This is what I have on my JWT:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
{
 “streamid”: “myStreamId”,
 “type”: “play”,
}
```

Little question, how can I also have, for example, 20min timeout for the viewers?

Comment: There's nothing magical about the JWT -- it's not encrypted, it's just additional state.  If you send the JWT to the client it can be copied to some other client.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a JWT is to provide integrity for the contents of the token - the contents is not (typically) encrypted, and it can be copied between systems.

You could do something like including the client's IP address and UserAgent in the JWT, and then comparing those to the ones you receive on the server. Spoofing a UserAgent is trivial, but doing it for an IP address over the public Internet is much harder.

It's certainly not bulletproof (and would allow people with the same proxy/public IP to re-use the tokens), but it would stop most casual viewers from just sharing tokens.

Ultimately though, you're essentially trying to implement your own version of DRM, which is a fundamentally flawed concept. If you allow a user to view your stream, you *cannot* stop them from record or re-broadcasting it, unless you have completely control (both in terms of software and hardware) of their setup.

Comment: +1. The idea of putting the IP in the JWT is a clever one, but it only prevents other IPs from directly accessing the original stream. There's nothing to prevent e.g. the valid-IP client from re-transmitting the video to anybody who wants it, or the valid-IP client running a transparent HTTP proxy that relays the requests and responses for arbitrary IPs and attaches the required JWT. It also will break horribly if somebody e.g. pays for access while at a cafe, and then leaves and tries to resume watching at home.

Comment: @CBHacking there is no technical means to stop a user retransmitting a video unless you have complete control of the software and hardware stack.

Comment: Right, did it seem I was claiming otherwise? My comment was to point out additional attacks based on what you'd said, including reasons why spoofing the IP address isn't hard at all _if_ you have a cooperative attacker with the relevant IP.

Comment: If you have a cooperative attacker than there is no possible defence anyway.